# Peculiar bug of %timeit when passing the set {1} as an argument

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I ran into a strange behaviour of the `timeit` magic function.

```
def f(S):
    for x in S:
        pass
%timeit f({3})
```

raises a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

This is while `%timeit f(set([3]))`
works,
and also
`%timeit f({1,2})` works.

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Ah,  you are hitting one of the edge case of magics, `$variable` and `{variable}` are meant to interpolate python variable. That is to say `{foo}` will be replaced by the value of `str(foo)`. That is useful for shell execution for example, `%bash rm {myfile}`. To convince yourself of that, run timeit with `-n1 -r1` (run only one loop `-r1`, once `-n1`), and print `S`:

```
In [1]: def f(S):
  ...:     print(S)
  ...:
  ...: %timeit -r1 -n1  f({3})
3
92.6 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Oh, we got `3` instead of `{3}`.... solution, double the `{}`:

```
In [2]: def f(S):
  ...:     print(S)
  ...:
  ...: %timeit -r1 -n1  f({{3}})
{3}
25.9 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Good ! Let's fix your example:

```
In [3]: def f(S):
  ...:     for x in S:
  ...:         pass
  ...: %timeit f({{3}})
234 ns ± 3.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

And you can open a bug on https://github.com/ipython/ipython, I'm pretty sure there is already one open if there are enough complain we may change the behavior at some point; or at least document it. It's likely triggered by `{3}` and not `{1,2}` because `{3}` is "bracket-identifier-bracket" like `{foo}`, but `{1,2}` is not.

Note that `{k}` may be use to pass options to timeit itself if you've completely understood this answer:

```
In [4]: r=1
   ...: n=2
   ...: %timeit -n{n} -r{r} 1+1
292 ns ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 2 loops each)
```